Push notification limits on FCM HTTP V1 and I am under spark plan
we are using Firebase HTTPV1 and i am under spark plan(No cost)
How many message can i send per day, per month and per second and i am using same project for all the push notifications and Is there any throttling on push message for FCM HTTPV1?
we are getting few message drops while doing more pushes via REST Call with java code

FCM is free and unlimited for all Firebase plans. It doesn’t impose a limit on the number of messages you send, but there is a limit on how many messages you may send per second. Please refer to the documentation to get more information on FCM limits. Please note that the quotas can be increased for the project/user by the Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) Product Engineering Team.
Also, you can refer to the FCM reporting dashboard, for the insight into message delivery to your app, which records the number of messages sent and opened on Apple and Android devices, along with data for "impressions" for Android apps.
